# jQuery Simulate clicking a link on page load using the link attributes

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and working on an gallery website where the home page has a widget that shows the latest image added to the gallery page.

The gallery page shows all images and when you click on an image it opens a lightbox to view the image while remaining on the gallery page. It does this by checking for a specific class on the link and, if present, opens the lightbox. If not, it just goes wherever the link points as normal.

I want users who click on the preview image in the homepage widget to go to the gallery page and then have that image open up in the lightbox. I've made progress but I'm currently stuck on a very specific problem...

If the user clicks the link manually the browser "sees" the class that regulates whether to open in lightbox or not but if I use jQuery to simulate a user click on that link it doesn't see the class, so the lightbox doesn't open and instead the user is just sent to the image directly.

Is there a way to genuinely simulate a browser click on page load that takes into account the attributes on the link, such as the link class?

If not is there some other way I can accomplish this?

EDIT - this is the jQuery I'm using to accomplish what I have so far

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(\"a[href$='someimage.jpg']\")[0].click();

    });
</script>
```

and this is the link it's working on

```
<a href="someimage.jpg" class="foobox" target="_self" rel="available-works- 
    figures"><img width="150" height="150" 
    src="someimage.jpg" class="pt-cv-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
```

The lighbox plugin checks to see if the link has the class "foobox" and if so, it opens in a lightbox. If it doesn't, it doesn't - just opens as a link normally would.

When the jQuery fires it seems to ignore the class "foobox" on the link because it also just opens as a normal link, going right to the image instead of displaying it in the lightbox the way it does if someone actually clicks on the link.

Hopefully that explains a little better what is going on.

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quotes around your selector?  And why the `[0]`?  Neither are necessary.  My guess - your click is triggering before Lightbox has initialised, meaning it isn't listening and ready to handle clicks on `.foobox` elements.  Can you put your code after wherever you initialise Lightbox?

Comment: So this is actually going to happen inside some PHP code that checks to see if a specific post variable is set, which is why the escape. I'm also using [0] because I've tried basically every other possible variation to get this working and nothing else has. I believe the code controlling the lightbox should be initialized because that is done with PHP, so unless I'm mistaken, the jQuery doesn't actually process until after the PHP, right?

Comment: Lightbox requires jQuery, so it can't start until jQuery is ready (`$(document).ready()`. Find wherever Lightbox is initialised, and add your JS *after* that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where it would be initialized as the functionality comes from a plugin but I will see what I can find!

Comment: So I think I found it in the header.... Is this what I'm looking for?

`<script type="text/javascript">
/* Run FooBox FREE (v2.7.8) */
var FOOBOX = window.FOOBOX = {
 ready: true,
 preloadFont: false,
 disableOthers: false,
 o: {wordpress: { enabled: true }, countMessage:'image %index of %total', excludes:'.fbx-link,.nofoobox,.nolightbox,a[href*="pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"]', affiliate : { enabled: false }},
 selectors: [
  ".gallery", ".wp-block-gallery", ".wp-caption", ".wp-block-image", "a:has(img[class*=wp-image-])", ".foobox"
 ],
};`

Comment: Is it actually called Foobox? You should really mention that in your question - Lightbox is a very popular and widely used lightbox plugin, I just assumed that's what you were using, and I was reading it's docs the other day when looking at your issue.  Yes, that looks like the code that initialises the plugin. Where does your code appear in relation to that?

Comment: My code is posted below that - that is located in the header, whereas mine is located further down in the page content of the gallery page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the document ready event of jquery

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

You can use trigger metho inside document ready.

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: This is how I'm currently doing this but it doesn't seem to see the class on the link so it just opens the image directly in the browser window instead of opening in the lightbox.

Comment: It will be helpful if you paste some code so that anyone can give you a better answer.

Comment: Updated - hopefully that helps!